# Interpretation of regression result

Tags: regression, least-squares, stata

I have a problem related to understanding a coefficient of a regression I have made.

Some of the variables in my dataset looks like this: "SKDchange" is the variable of interest as dependent variable, while I struggle to interpret the diff1Equity variable. The regression in on changes-changes form where both the explanatory and dependent variable measures the change from t-1 to t.

My regression code looks like this:
reg SKDchange diff1Bokførtavkastning diff1Verdijustertavkastning diff1Diff diff1NPVrentegar diff1Duration diff1Innskutt_EK diff1Annen_EK diff1Tilleggsavsetning diff1Kursreguleringsfond diff1Premiefond diff1Equity diff1IG diff1HY diff1HF diff1PE diff1Eiendom i.Year i.id, vce(cluster id Year)

Code:

- Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
  clear
  input float(diff1Equity diff1IG diff1Duration SKDchange)
  .            .             .     .
  .04754161   -.09403566     -.1599999   -.3
  -.02064644  -.018740425     .54999995  -.14
  .010813517   -.01095776          -.25  -.02
  -.026318334  -.002717563           .71  -.29
  .05093006  -.005377363          -.43  -.12
  -.0011152852  -.013379592     .13000004   .07
  -.024114784    .04315393    .029999923   .27
  .02377115   -.04732417           .48   .16
  -.030893333    .03741644     .22999993   .12
  .02928274    .02414991          1.65    .3
  .001455957  .0004799768     .26000005   .22
  .004779475    .00558187    -.27000016  -.07
  .            .             .     .
  -.00512642   .004711266    -.10917584  -.07
  -.063273735    .04655176     .26596162  -.18
  .02563643   -.02877299         -.355  -.03
  -.04105696    .15782078     -.2039706   .19
  .009601564  -.010468778     .10676478  -.41
  .02057601    .02437022     .11147057   .14
  .02281441  -.012794206   -.011764593   .04
  -.1235865    .11275683          1.35   .08
  -.04838456 -.0012550277         -2.28  -.17
  -.0041883523    .01323345          3.05   .43
  .012058506  -.015719667    -2.0700002   .09
  -.005533226 -.0021816033          1.45   .03
  .            .             .     .
  .06241516   -.05142799    -.19732134  -.04
  -.0014952082  -.001770217      .9085715  -.91
  .04270349   -.06381753     -.7399999   .52
  .09990668   -.11121875     .32000005   -.2
  -.02076794   -.02086097      .6300001   .24
  .02764053    -.1214763         -1.75   .61
  -.04209387   -.03557081     .03099999  -.29
  .02711773   -.08156485      .2990001  -.05
  -.04882512    .06585504     .28000006  -.12
  -.04681846    .05470577      .2000001   .05
  .11536504   -.07811742     .20000005   .09
  .06964771   .013372925           -.8  -.15
  .            .             .     .
  -.0887506   .031709056      .8700001  -.13
  -.08438469    -.4525758     .05999994  -.26
  .02664301  -.007119911            -1  -.05
  .0045617344    .02329633             0   .06
  -.0021377348    .04008004         -1.43   .26
  -.01407777    .03055194    -.16999993  -.04
  .010314748   -.02585671         -1.76   .16
  .02583596   .031915076 -5.960464e-10   .07
  -.01983064  -.014577777          2.63  -.23
  -.0041912617     .1929425     .13833335   .01
  -.08911186    -.2353105     .06904765   .51
  .032503515    .04405855       .286619   .01
  .            .             .     .
  .02059753    .00604589    -1.4834615   .33
  -.012380703   -.06797267      .5134616  -.41
  .016461588   .018263668          -2.8   .19
  -.016667238   .001590435            .1    .3
  -.024444895   .024264194           .75   .23
  .007214402  -.013604298          1.56  -.51
  .1661422   -.08117536     -.8400001   .09
  .03991343   -.04297239     .10000005  -.21
  .0945853    -.1083463  2.384186e-08  -.11
  .09561862   -.10853375    -.09999998   -.2
  -.3036081    .27654004            .4   .83
  .0191042   -.04063289      .4999999  -.18
  .            .             .     .
  .028694145   -.07184994     -.4087499  1.04
  -.11852485   .065436386     -.2100001   .83
  .06047443   -.08638582           -.3   .08
  -.00934424   .008003984    -.19999997  -.12
  .05878297    .05886357     .19999996  -.66
  -.03458966    .04444094            .2  -.02
  -.01792603    -.0598651     -.6999999   .85
  .009644688    .03987899           -.3  -.93
  .004996592  -.006057756 -2.384186e-08  -.17
  .0002828524   -.10505882            .4   .61
  -.01864195  -.002772984          -.14  1.31
  .031855654    .08679447          1.01 -1.65
  .            .             .     .
  .012399666    .06262513    -.19732134    .1
  -.22266704   -.05568459    -.07587294   .19
  .1560319    .11884157    .022385584  -.44
  .03940175   .016805476    -.28460786  -.34
  .017667945   -.04138368     -.3033333   .12
  -.007013578  .0078530125    -.52000004   .56
  -.06908407     -.072072      .6799999   .34
  .06103085    .04783031      .2599999   .17
  -.02623497    .07248117     -.1000001   .19
  .04369584   -.03614791     .57000005   -.1
  .02110185   -.04804264     1.0100001  -.05
  .0099649 -.0017389223     .11999989  -.15
  .            .             .     .
  .08086738  -.014327994    -.10917584  -.58
  -.12395176   -.05033401     .26596162  -.05
  -.15088338    .13968238         -.355   .19
  .04139739    .20281895     -.2039706  -.15
  .035840575   -.16239823     .10676478  -.17
  .11057469  .0003425852     .11147057   -.2
  -.005472437   -.02754408   -.011764593   .17
  .03027286    .05957837         -2.28   .13
  end
  What I get out of the regression is shown in the attachment. What I don't totally is how to interpret the coefficients for diff1duration which is measured in years, and diff1Equity against the dependent variable SKDchange. (I do not understand diff1IG etc. either but the interpretation would be the same as for diff1Equity).The data is in the following scale. A change in the relative allocation to Equity of 1 percentage point will show as a diff1Equity of 0.01. The dependent variable will return 0.25 if the percentage point change in the dependent variable is 25.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Is one unit here referring to a 1% increase or a one percentage point?

[image]